# Bootstrap v3.3.7 panel not collapsing correctly after setting the height

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.3.7 panels. When I click on the icon to slide up the panel everything works fine panel hides and animations are smooth. Please see the following example:

```js
$('.panel-collapse').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);


        if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
        } else {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
            $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/
font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"/>

             <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary form-horizontal product-Section-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Panel 1
                        <a class="pull-right"><span class="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">                 </i></span></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary form-horizontal product-Section-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Panel 1
                        <a class="pull-right"><span class="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">                 </i></span></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The problem occur once I set the panel height the panel it self does not hides anymore apart from the panel content body which gets slide up. Please see the following:

```js
$('.panel-collapse').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);


        if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
        } else {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
            $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
        }
    });
```

```css
.product-Section-panel
    { 
        min-height: 280px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/
font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"/>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary form-horizontal product-Section-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Panel 1
                        <a class="pull-right"><span class="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">                 </i></span></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary form-horizontal product-Section-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Panel 1
                        <a class="pull-right"><span class="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">                 </i></span></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The current approach that I did to fix this is to set the height on the panel-body as follows    `<div class="panel-body product-Section-panel">` but than the animation is not smooth anymore. How can I set panel height while allowing to collapse the panel and animation is smooth.

Comment: Why are you doing all that manual manipulation instead of using [Bootstrap's collapse functions](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-methods)?

Comment: @isherwood same issue when setting the height. Can you provide an answer based on what I provided

Comment: @isherwood yes basically when I set the panel height the issue occurs. so when collapsing the panel without setting the height the panel collapses fine and the animations are smooth but when setting the height of panel panel is not collapsing as expected. and yo answer your question why not to use collapse function did just try that but same issue remained so just to fix the issue can we focus on fixing the issue based on the code provided if nothing has worked will than look deeper at your suggested way which did not work when I quickly tried it

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
$('.panel-collapse').on('click', function (e) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var prodSectionPanel = $this.parents('.product-Section-panel')
        
        var prodSectionPanelHeight = 0;
        if (!$this.hasClass('panel-collapsed')) {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideUp();
            $this.addClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-up').addClass('fa-chevron-down');
        } else {
            $this.parents('.panel').find('.panel-body').slideDown();
            $this.removeClass('panel-collapsed');
            $this.find('i').removeClass('fa-chevron-down').addClass('fa-chevron-up');
            prodSectionPanelHeight = '280px';
        }
        document.documentElement.style.minHeight = prodSectionPanelHeight;
    });
```

```css
.product-Section-panel {
  transition: min-height .4s;
  will-change: min-height;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/
font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css"/>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary form-horizontal product-Section-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Panel 1
                        <a class="pull-right"><span class="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">                 </i></span></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary form-horizontal product-Section-panel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">
                        Panel 1
                        <a class="pull-right"><span class="panel-collapse"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up">                 </i></span></a>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Label1</label>
              <input type="text">
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I have looked at the solution. it works if there is only one panel but the problem that I am facing that there are multiple panel set in a row. when one collapses. the other do changes in height

Comment: I see, could you edit your example to show the problem you are actually facing?

Comment: Answer edited I kind made a solution that did not fully work but if you can provide a solution to the issue that would be much better if you look at the second code snippet it has two panel and when doing you approach kind not fully work

Comment: The answer has been updated.

Comment: Yes I have looked at your answer and I did a similar solution my self but the problem that I am still face and that you did not yet consider my friend is that you did not set the min-height as I did mention in the code. so in CSS you will need to set the min-height as a default height for all panel beside updating them in JavaScript